# Сумма объектов из JSON и создание нового JSON

Tags: javascript, json, zabbix

Всем привет! У меня есть код, считающий сумму значений "price" из всех объектов JSON:

```js
var json = '[{"id":0,"price":"100"},{"id":1,"price":"50.95"}]';

var data = JSON.parse(json);

function calc (arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    arr.forEach(function (item) {
        var n = +item.price;
        sum += n;
    });
    
    return sum;
}

var sum = calc(data);
console.log(sum);
```

У меня есть JSON:

```
[
   {
      "{#SNMPINDEX}":"1",
      "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"3"
   },
   {
      "{#SNMPINDEX}":"2",
      "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"2"
   },
   {
      "{#SNMPINDEX}":"3",
      "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"3"
   },
   {
      "{#SNMPINDEX}":"4",
      "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"2"
   }
]
```

Мне нужно модернизировать код, чтобы он мог считать сумму всех {#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS} и на выходе создавать JSON с одним объектом, вот пример:

```
[
   {
      "{#SNMPINDEX}":"1",
      "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"10"
   }
]
```

{#SNMPINDEX} всегда должен быть 1, а в {#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS} сумма из предыдущего JSON.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы серьёзно не можете заменить ключ в одном коде на другой ключ?

Comment: К сожалению да...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой ответ удовлетворяет условию задачи.

```js
var data = [
   {
  "{#SNMPINDEX}":"1",
  "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"3"
   },
   {
  "{#SNMPINDEX}":"2",
  "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"2"
   },
   {
  "{#SNMPINDEX}":"3",
  "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"3"
   },
   {
  "{#SNMPINDEX}":"4",
  "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"2"
   }
];

var result = data.reduce((acc, item)=> {acc[0]["{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}"] =""+(+(acc[0]["{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}"]) + (+(item["{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}"]))); return acc}, [{
    "{#SNMPINDEX}":"1",
    "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"0"
   }]);


console.log(result);
```

**Upd** проверял на `https://jsfiddle.net/`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо @Grundy добавил скобок не думал что это так критично.

Comment: Если данный код выполнить здесь, то всё работает, а если выполнить на jsfiddle.net то выдает ошибку, в коде подсвечивается ошибка (confusing plusses). В Zabbix предобработке, куда я вставляю код тоже ошибка.

Comment: мой код работает нормально

Comment: @АртемЧернышев, на эту часть ругается скорее всего: `+ +(item` просто либо Number используй вместо второго плюса либо в скобки дополнительно оберни

Comment: @Grundy, да ругается на это, сейчас попробую, спасибо!

Comment: @АртемЧернышев добавил скобок. спс Grundy

Comment: @AzizUmarov, вопрос, насколько Ваш код совместим с ducktape? Просто в Zabbix javascript предобработка, реализована при помощи Duktape. Там Ваш код не работает(

Comment: Проблема ясна. Думаю тут можно пометить а следом создать вопрос с этими коментариями

Answer (score 1):

```
let json = `
[
    {
       "{#SNMPINDEX}":"1",
       "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"3"
    },
    {
       "{#SNMPINDEX}":"2",
       "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"2"
    },
    {
       "{#SNMPINDEX}":"3",
       "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"3"
    },
    {
       "{#SNMPINDEX}":"4",
       "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":"2"
    }
 ]
`;

let data = JSON.parse(json);

function calc (arr, valName) {
    let sum = 0;
    return arr.reduce( (accumulator, currentValue) => {
        return accumulator + Number(currentValue[valName]);
    }, sum);
    
}

function makeJsonResult(data) {
    let sum = calc(data, "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}");
    return {
            "{#SNMPINDEX}":"1",
            "{#BSNDOT11ESSNUMBEROFMOBILESTATIONS}":sum
    }
}

console.log(makeJsonResult(data));
```